# approximate $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} k! n^{-k} \sim {\sqrt{\pi n}\over \sqrt{2}}$

Tags: combinatorics, approximation, factorial, gamma-function, binomial-theorem

Show that as $ n \to \infty $

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} k! n^{-k} \sim {\sqrt{\pi n}\over \sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of the $\Gamma$ function and the binomial theorem:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{n^k} &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}\,dx \\ &=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n e^{-x}\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the last integral can be approximated by using Laplace's method.

Since $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)e^{-x/n}\approx e^{-\frac{x^2}{2n^2}}$, for large $n$s we have:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{n^k} \approx \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2n}\right)\,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$$
as wanted.

Comment: could you please explain how (1+x/n)e^(-x/n) can be approximated as e^(-x^2/2n^2)? thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: @HoagSeki: from basic Taylor series, we know that if $z$ is close to zero then: $$\log(1+z)-z = -\frac{z^2}{2}+\ldots $$ Just exponentiate both sides and set $z=\frac{x}{n}$ to recover the shown approximation.

Comment: @HoagSeki: you're welcome.